# how to write sql query in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

hello  friends i have this query that runs using sql editor but i have no idea how to write this query using laravel.please help me out.

```
SELECT 
  date,
  memo,
 (COALESCE(CASE WHEN drcr = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) total_debits,
 (COALESCE(CASE WHEN drcr = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) total_credits,
@b := @b + (COALESCE(CASE WHEN drcr = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) - (COALESCE(CASE WHEN drcr = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) balance
FROM
(SELECT @b := 0.0) AS dummy 
CROSS JOIN
tbl_bankrecords
ORDER BY
date
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
Model::select(DB::raw('SELECT 
  date
 ,memo
 ,(COALESCE(CASE WHEN drcr = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) total_debits
 ,(COALESCE(CASE WHEN drcr = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) total_credits,
@b := @b + (COALESCE(CASE WHEN drcr = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) - (COALESCE(CASE WHEN drcr = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) balance'))->get();
```

Comment: hello siddharth how to add this part.will you please ellaborate it.FROM
(SELECT @b := 0.0) AS dummy 
CROSS JOIN
tbl_bankrecords
ORDER BY
date

Comment: Just try to put all the things mentioned by you in `Model::select(DB::raw('PUT YOUR RAW QUERY HERE'))->get();`. I'm not sure of it but this should work

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#running-queries) should be helpful for you, Anyhow below is the sample code from Laravel documentation.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Show a list of all of the application's users.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
 public function index()
 {
    $users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);

    return view('user.index', ['users' => $users]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Raw Expressions
>
> Sometimes you may need to use a raw expression in a query. These expressions will be injected into the query as strings, so be careful not to create any SQL injection points! To create a raw expression, you may use the DB::raw method:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
   ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
   ->where('status', '<>', 1)
   ->groupBy('status')
   ->get();
```

[Laravel Doc for Raw Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries)

Also :

```
$someVariable = Input::get("some_variable");

$results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_col = :somevariable"), array('somevariable' => $someVariable));
```

http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries